# mvim command in terminal will launch macvim but won't open the file I pass to it as an argument?

Tags: macos, vim, console, macvim

I have this weird problem. mvim alias in terminal will launch macvim without problem but if I do, for example

```
~$ mvim .vimrc
```

mvim will launch on an empty file and .vimrc will be opened in TextEdit..
how can I fix that? This is pretty annoying!

Comment: For me, `mvim` is a script, not alias. Can you show us what your alias looks like?

Comment: I've added 
alias mvim="open /Applications/MacVim.app" to my .bash_profile

Comment: never mind I've deleted that useless alias. I've added the mvim file that comes in the application folder in /usr/local/bin which I've added to my path but its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but I had created an alias in .bash_profile. After deleting that useless alias, everything worked!